# Java enum - return String

Tags: java, enums, tostring

I need to create an element repository for my app.

This is the class I created.

```
public class Elements
{
  public enum Type1
  {
    A    ("text1"),
    B    ("text2"),
    C    ("text3"),
    D    ("text4"),
    E    ("text5");

    private String identifier;

    Type1(String identifier)
    {
      this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    getPath()
    {
      String path = "";
      //do something
      return path;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can access the values using `Elements.type1.A.getPath();`

I did a static import of Elements.type1 and I want to remove the usage of getPath() because it would complicate my code. ie. I need to be able to use `type1.A`.

So I did,

```
public class Elements
{
  public enum Type1
  {
    A
      {
        public String toString()
        {
          return getPath("text1");
        }
      },
    B
      {
        public String toString()
        {
          return getPath("text2");
        }
      },
    C
      {
        public String toString()
        {
          return getPath("text3");
        }
      };

    Type1() {}
  }
}
```

Now I can use `Elements.Type1.A` with print statements but I have a method which accepts String as parameter.

So that makes it `Elements.Type1.A.toString()`. Without toString(), it throws an error.

Is there a method to get rid of `toString()`?

**Edit : New Code**

```
public Interface Type1 
{
   String A = "text1";
   String B = "text2";
   String C = "text3"; 
}
public class Utility 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     getPath(Type1.A); 
   }
   public static void getPath(String arg) 
   { 
    //Constructs xpath - text1 changes to //*[contains(@class,'text1')] 
    return xpath; 
   } 
} 
public class myClass 
{
   public void doSomething() 
   {
     assertEquals(Type1.A,xpath); 
   } 
}
```

Here, Type1.A returns "text1" and not //*[contains(@class,'text1')]

Comment: The only reason you can _avoid_ using `toString()` normally is because `+` and System.out/System.err knows how to do it under the covers.

Comment: First don't use `toString` to return something other than just 'String representation of the object'. How do client of this class know that this is actually some 'path'?
And for your question, you can overload your method to take enum param, extract necessary property from it and pass it to original method.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you need three String constants not enums.

```
public static final String A = "test1";
public static final String B = "test2";
public static final String C = "test3";
```

Using an interface is not always best, but without further context I can't suggest something better

```
public interface Type1 {
    String A = "test1";
    String B = "test2";
    String C = "test3";
}
```

Comment: but I need to do some operation on the value before returning it. Is that possible?

Comment: Also, I need to use Type1 to denote A belongs to Type1

Comment: The idea of declaring them as string variables helped. I am accepting this answer because the discussion started from here. Thanks @RohitJain.

Comment: @Aswathi. You're welcome. And its absolutely no problem. You should only accept the answer that suits your need. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, as `Peter` said, you need `final static` variables here..

Looks, like you want a set of `String Constants` to work with.. Then definitely you should work with what `Peter` has quoted..

**Just to extends what he said**, you can create an Interface, and have all your String Constants in it.. Then you can easily access them through `Interface` name..

```
public Interface Type1 {
    String A = "text1";
    String B = "text2";
    String C = "text3";
}
```

**And somewhere in your other class: -**

```
public class Utility {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // You can pass your String to any method..
        String a = Type1.A;

        getPath(a);
        getPath(Type1.B);          

    }

    // This method is not doing work according to its name..
    // I have just taken an example, you can use this method to do what you want.
    public static void getPath(String arg) {
        // You can process your string here.
        arg = arg + "Hello";
    }
}
```

You can also change what your `toString()` returns based on your needs..

And follow `Java Naming Convention`.. Enums, Classes start with `Uppercase` letters..

Comment: It is not possible to create an object of Type1 for each value in the enum since there would be 100s of them.

Comment: @Aswathi.. What exactly you want to have. You need to be more specific.. As far as I can make out from your comment, you want a set of String constants?? Am I understand it right??

Comment: I need to create an element repository. The identifiers have to be stored somewhere and when a user accesses an element, the element identifier has to be processed using a method getPath() and the resulting xpath needs to be returned. I want the element access to be as simple as possible; maybe like Type1.btnSave. btnSave will have different identifier depending on the Type.

Comment: But as I mentioned earlier, since there would be 100s of strings in the interface, it is not possible to declare a variable for each of them. Is there an alternate solution? Am really sorry if am being stupid.

Comment: @Aswathi.. You don't need to declare a variable.. Just you can access it directly.. And in any ways you have to have those 100 constants in your interface..

Comment: @Aswathi.. An interface is the best way to handle any number of Constants.. You can directly access like:  -  `Type1.A` will give you "text1".. And don't be sorry.. No question is small or big..

Comment: Ok so now I have an interface with the constants. In the main() of the implementing class Utility, I called getPath(Type1.A). When I try to access Utility.A, it prints the value specified in the interface, not the processed one.

Comment: @Aswathi.. Can you post your Updated code in the OP.. And what do you want your `getPath` method to do??

Comment: @Aswathi.. You are trying to update a constant value and access it.. Which is not possible..

Comment: Where are you getting `xpath` in your `myclass`?? :- `assertEquals(Type1.A,xpath);`  here??

Comment: Also, I don't see any relation between your `Utility` class and `myClass`.. Please explain what you want to do more clearly.. I can't explain better untill I understand your problem better..